# Subsites not inheriting theme changes

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I have modified the spcolor file to my liking on my root site and applied it.  Works great and the changes I've made to the color on my top bar looks like I want.

But the subsites are unaffected.  When I go into the "Change the Look" and pick current, I see the color change.  But when I "Try it out", it goes back to the old look.  Applying it doesn't make any difference.  Thoughts to help out a simple DBA?

Comment: At this point I have no problem manually going into the subsites and changing them to the new colors, but the fact remains that it's still not working and I don't know where to go with this.

Answer (score 1):

From your root site collection, Goto Site settings > look and feel > select master page> apply to this site and its subsites. Your master page along with theme will be applied to all subsites. Let me know if this works

Comment: You should add that if the top site is not a publishing site, the site collection publishing feature must be activated to get the master page option.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't see the option to activate that feature.  When I go to https://{servername}/_layouts/15/ManageFeatures.aspx, it's not there.

Comment: Thanks, Nate, but I don't see what you commented on as well.  I assume that because I can't enable the feature this is why I don't see it.

Comment: Looks like you need Enterprise for this.  I have Foundation.

Comment: You should have this feature on foundation. You should look under site actions> manage site features, turn on  "sharepoint server publishing" feature.